# jquery find index of element with selector

Tags: jquery, list

I'm trying to use .index() function of jQuery and I can figure out how it works. Results are not what I expect them to me. Here is a little exemple of why I don't get it :

Html :

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-item">item 1</div>
  <div class="gallery-item active">item 2</div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
  <div class="gallery-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="gallery-item">item 4</div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="next">next</button>
</div>
<span id="console">
</span>
```

JS :

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $("#buttons > #next").click(function (){
        var items = $(".gallery-item");

        var index = items.find(".active").index();
        $("#console").append("index : " + index + "<br />");

        var indexWithSelector = items.index(".active");
        $("#console").append("index with selector : " + indexWithSelector + "<br />");

        var prevAll = items.prevAll(".gallery-item").size();
        $("#console").append("prevall : " + prevAll + "<br />");

        $.each(items, function(index, val) {
            $("#console").append("<br />" + val.className);
        });
    });

});
```

I expect all results to be the same : 1 as the active element is the second in a zero-based list. But I get this :

```
index : -1
index with selector : -1
prevall : 3

gallery-item
gallery-item active
gallery-item
gallery-item
```

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Here it is on CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meiBA

Update :

I tried to find the active element directly and use index to find it's position and it worked. I tried this :

```
var active = $(".gallery-item.active");
var index = items.index(active);
//index == 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code in jsfiddle .I found that you are getting -1 because the element index that you are trying to find doesnt exist in that context :

```
 var items = $(".gallery-item");        
 var index = items.find(".active").index();
```

Here items.find will return nothing but empty jquery object.You are trying to find the active class in the child items of the gallery item .But active class is at same level of other gallery-item.So the code should be like this :

```
 var index = items.filter(".active").index();
```

That is the reason you was getting this -1 .As there was no element so index was returning as -1.

```
index : -1
```

Now lets talk about this :

```
index with selector : -1
```

The reason behind this -1 is the following code :

```
var indexWithSelector = items.index(".active");
```

Here you are finding the `$(".gallery-item")` in collection of `.active` class.Which is making no sense.
As `.active` is the part of gallery-item.

The search should be like this :

```
 var indexWithSelector = items.filter(".active").index(".gallery-item");
```

Now lets check the following code :

```
var prevAll = items.prevAll(".gallery-item").size();
```

Here you are trying to get size of all previous items.Where the size of items is 4 i.e of `$(".gallery-item")` and its returning you the size 4-1 = 3 which is correct.

If you was trying to get the prev `gallery-item` of `active` class then code should be :

```
var prevAll = items.filter(".active").prevAll(".gallery-item").size();
```

So the correct output will look like :

```
index : 1 
index with selector : 1
prevall : 1
```

And last but not the least here is the jsfiddle.I commented your code as well so that you can comment mine and check the effect :

[**DEMO** : **JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/srahel007/Bwy78/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I guess I was misusing both the find and index function. And I didn't know prevAll would wrap around the list.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a little weird that I can find the active object, pass it in the index function on the items collection and make it works when I can't use the selector.

Intuition would lead me to believe that .index("with a selector") on a collection would give me the index of the first element matching the selector within the collection on which the method is called.

Comment: I would suggest you to check the api of index ( selectors) .it will give u a clear picture .that the selector Here is collection of elements and we check the index of element from that collection .hope I answered your question

Comment: I would suggest you to check the api of index ( selectors) .it will give u a clear picture .that the selector Here is collection of elements and we check the index of element from that collection .hope I answered your question

Answer (score 0):

`var index = items.find(".active").index();` wouldn't work because find() methods finds it's contents not it's class so you can use [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method:

```
var index = items.hasClass(".active").index();
```

Comment: That wouldn't work has hasClass would return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
items.index($("div.active"));
```

instead of

```
items.find(".active").index();
```

here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/rMLNH/1/

Comment: That makes it work, now can you tell me why index("with a selector"); isn't doing it for me?

Comment: actually items.index($("div.active")); says find the index of $("div.active") (which is jQuery element) in items. but items.find(".active").index(); says find('.active') (which is a html dom element not a jquery element) in items. So difference is jquery element vs simple dom element.